# Finding Anaconda's directory in Windows 10 through an installer created with Visual Studio's Setup Project plugin

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, windows-10, visual-studio-2019

I'm making an installer for Windows 10 that installs some files within Anaconda's installation path. For this, I'm using Visual Studio (2019 -- version 16.9.4) and the Setup Project plugin (version 0.9.9). I have added a "Registry Launch Condition" following the instructions explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/h0z89y5d(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) (that I found after reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48273612/12075306)) so that the installer finds Anaconda's directory automatically, without having to assume the Anaconda's default installation path (given [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/faq/)).

For the installer, I have managed to create a registry search condition and link it to the files that are to be installed in such a way that if the search fails then the installer prompts an error message (that I know how to edit).

I haven't managed, however, to introduce a proper "RegKey" to find anaconda in the registry. As a matter of fact, I don't even know how to find Anaconda in the Windows' Registry Editor app.

**Question 1:** What is (are) the registry key (keys) related to Anaconda?

I can't find this answer anywhere. I need a registry key that gives me Anaconda's root directory,

```
C:\...\Anaconda3
```

or any other of these paths

```
C:\...\Anaconda3\Lib
C:\...\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages
```

**Question 2:** *If* the only registry key entry available does not give any of these three paths (listed above) but rather some other path *within* Anaconda's root directory, then how can such a path be modified to get one of those three listed above?

Thank you all! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer this question so that others have the chance to solve, if not the same, similar issues. I managed to find what I was looking for by searching folder by folder the registry via the registry editor app. The registry key that I need is displayed on the bar below the dropdown menus "File", "Edit", .... You just need to remove the `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\` and keep the rest `SOFTWARE\Python\ContinuumAnalytics\Anaconda38-64\InstallPath`. This, I believe, if anaconda was installed with python 3.8.

[image]